# Virtualenv issues,django packages

Tags: python, django

While working in django project in pycharm ,I got an error it said "install django package" but I already installed django in my virtualenv.If I install global django package in pycharm will it affect my virtualenv ?

Comment: You should change the Python interpeter location to the binary in the virtual environment

Comment: see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html#python_create_virtual_env

Answer (score 0):

Check if the interpreter in pycharm is the virtual environment you created.

Here is a manual by [jetbrains](http://Check%20if%20the%20interpreter%20in%20pycharm%20is%20the%20virtual%20environment%20you%20created.%20%20Here%20is%20a%20manual%20by%20jetbrains%20https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html#python_create_virtual_env)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).